Hugo Website pages visible when locally served but not through github pages
I'm a relative novice using hugo, and I recently used the blogdown package to create a hugo website. I'm using the academic theme, which I forked from this github repository.
While creating my content, I would often use the blogdown::serve_site() command to check out how my site looked in the process. Once I was happy with it, I served it publicly through Github pages. However, not all of the page links are visible on the github pages version. For example, under the "Recent & Upcoming Talks" section, there is only one entry listed on the public version, even though there are two entries in the "content/event/" directory, both of which show up when I serve locally (screenshot attached).
The Github repository for the site is publicly visible here: https://github.com/GTFoster/InterMod
The publicly served site is visible here: https://gtfoster.github.io/
In case it's relevant, I did all of the creation and local serving using R 4.3.2 on ubuntu.
I expected that when I served through pages through a github action with details on this file https://github.com/GTFoster/GTFoster.github.io/blob/main/hugo.yml.
It successfully serves, but does not include all of the pages I expect, as described above.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Pages with future dates won't be rendered unless --buildFuture flag is present.
For example, https://github.com/GTFoster/GTFoster.github.io/blob/main/content/event/ESA2024/index.md date is set as 2024-08-04.
